# Rename class inside a tag with no id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hy can someone tell my ho to rename the class fb_connect to fb_connect2 with javascript?

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-ezformstep1">
<h3 class="legend">
<a href="#null" class="fb_connect">Connect to facebook</a>
</h3>
</fieldset>
```

this should be the result

```
<fieldset id="fieldset-ezformstep1">
<h3 class="legend">
<a href="#null" class="fb_connect2">Connect to facebook</a>
</h3>
</fieldset>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
$(window).load(function(){ // or document ready but i suspect you need to wait for the window loaded event
    $('.fb_connect').toggleClass('fb_connect fb_connect2');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery (guessing by the tag), this is a possibility:

```
 $("#fieldset-ezformstep1 > h3.legend > a.fb_connect").attr("class","fb_connect2");
```

Don't forget to wait until **after** the DOM is ready to do so.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to do it without jquery:

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName('fb_connect');

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
    elems[i].className = elems[i].className.replace(/\bfb_connect\b/, 'fb_connect2');
}
```